# How can i handle variables like A1, A2,..., An in a loop? in R

Tags: r, loops

I have 10 different objects: a1, a2, ... a10.
All I need to do is make a simple change to each variable.
such as

```
a1$x <- a1$x + 1
a2$x <- a2$x + 1
...
a10$x <- a10$x + 1
```

and

```
a1[,'new_x']<-cumprod(a1$x)
a2[,'new_x']<-cumprod(a2$x)
...
a10[,'new_x']<-cumprod(a10$x)
```

I'd like to shrink these codes using a 'for' loop.
I tried

```
for(i in 1:10) {
ai[,'new_x'] <- cumprod(ai$x)
}
```

and of course it does not work.
Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: use `lapply(list(a1,a2,..,a10), function(x) x + 1)`

Comment: Does r not have arrays?

Comment: yes it does, what kind of objects are `a1,a2..` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your looping approach without first converting the objects to a single list or data frame if you use the `eval()` function to read the objects and the `assign()` function to write the objects.  For example:

```
a1 <- data.frame(x=1:5)
a2 <- data.frame(x=2:6)
a3 <- data.frame(x=3:7)

for(i in 1:3) {
  dfname <- paste0("a", i)
  df <- eval(parse(text=dfname))
  df$new_x <- cumprod(df$x)
  assign(dfname, df)
}

a1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the answer I really needed.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work because you cannot call an object by replacing a part of the name by iterator `i`. If you want to iterate you must first group the objects in one object like a `list` or a `data.frame`. From your code I infer that the a objects are data.frames, so the most logical here is to store them in a `list`.

```
a1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
a2 <- data.frame(x = 11:15)
a3 <- data.frame(x = 16:30)

a_list <- list(a1, a2, a3)

for(i in 1:length(a_list)){
  a_list[[i]]$x <- a_list[[i]]$x + 1
  a_list[[i]]$x_new <- cumsum(a_list[[i]]$x)
}
```

Alternative to the `for` loop you can use the apply family in R, this results in a bit cleaner code.

```
a_list <- list(a1, a2, a3)

lapply(a_list, function(df) {
  df$x <- df$x + 1
  df$x_new <- cumsum(df$x)
  return(df)
})
```

If your data frames have the exact same structure it is even more convenient to bind all to one data frame with an id column added from which data frame the row originates. Then using `dplyr` to make changes to it

```
library(dplyr)
a_df <- rbind(a1 %>% mutate(df = 1), a2 %>% mutate(df = 2), a3 %>%  mutate(df = 3))
a_df %>% mutate(x = x + 1) %>% group_by(df) %>% mutate(x_new = cumsum(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try your codes as well :)